# Deploy Azure AppService to Url: 404 + no worker is assigned to the app service plan. The site cannot serve any requests

Tags: azure, azure-devops, web-deployment, azure-resource-manager

I'm getting a 404 trying to access my azurewebsite.net

My Resource group contains an AppServicePlan, an AppService, SQL Server & SQL Database, a KeyVault & SignalR.

Locally everything works, the AppService is running, AppServicePlan is Ready (1App/0Slots),
Connected Services for SignalR & SQL are configured (in the menu you get when right-clicking WebProject > Publish). KeyVault is configured & accessible. Not sure if these are problem free though, as I keep getting NuGet Errors, stating unable to update NuGet Package.

When I right-click my WebProject & Publish, I get Message Publish has been succeeded. But when I click on the link, I get a 404.

I'm working with two pipelines in AzureDevops

Seeing as official documentation is always lagging behind and showing older interfaces, it has not been much of a help.
I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-release-pipeline/5-deploy-to-appservice this tutorial, did everything stated, but the last step, I didn't get the desired result (an accessible website through azurewebsites.net).

I have a Export template with all connected services configured (I guess generated by azure?) but don't really know what to do with it.

Can anybody pinpoint what I am missing or doing wrong? Or tell me what else I would be needing, apart from the services I mentioned (like Certificates, Active Directory?)
Do I need a gitHub repo next to AzureDevOps Repo & Azure Resources?
Does publishing via VS interfere with my automated pipelinebuilds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to deploy to Azure App Service in Azure DevOps directly. I used the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-release-pipeline/5-deploy-to-appservice) you shared and worked well on my side. Here are my steps:

1.Create the App Service instance in Azure and make sure the default home page is correct.

2.Clone the [sample](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-tailspin-spacegame-web-deploy) from GitHub to Azure DevOps Repo.

3.Change the deploy stage in the azure-pipelines.yml file on release branch and run pipeline. I removed variable groups and changed the configuration of AzureWebApp task:
[image]

4.Browse the page in Azure. I can get the same page as in the tutorial.

[image]

Comment: Quan-MSFT thank you for answer! I updated my release yaml like your screenshot but it still does not work. I think its strange that the pipeline in Azure DevOps pipelines doesn't show the yaml-inputted displayname. Also, could you please explain to me why I would need GitHub? I'm using DevOps as source control already, do I need the GitHub repo as well? Also: my ZipFile is in a folder called 'drop' but it has another name. If I want to 'download: current; artifact: drop' will he expect a drop.zip or will he look in folder called 'drop' and take the package name from inputs? Thx again!

Comment: 1.Can you share the screenshot about pipelines doesn't show the yaml-inputted displayname? 2.You do not need github. I just used the sample on github. 3.It will look in folder called 'drop' and take the package name from inputs.

Comment: Maybe you can clone my [sample](https://dev.azure.com/v-waqia/Sample/_git/mslearn-tailspin-spacegame-web-deploy.git) and just change the subscription name and app name in the yaml file.

Comment: screenshots: https://i.imgur.com/Uow2txK.png & https://i.imgur.com/lBez8Cr.png I've changed the name of the artifact now to make it more clear. It seems release pipeline finds the artifact produced by Build Pipeline. But have found I may have a problem in angular. I can ng build --prod, but when I ng run projectName:deploy I get 'Project target does not exist.' screenshot of my angular.json: https://i.imgur.com/UTohphg.png  browserTarget always points to projectName. I tried adding server, serve-ssr & prerender to architect (like other question suggested) by no difference...

Comment: @dfbenny I did not find angular.json in the sample of the tutorial. Did you add the files yourself? It seems that it is a different question, you can create a new ticket for this.

Comment: @Qian I believe the angular.json was generated. It seems indeed. I have made a new, more elaborate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66213224/ng-run-projectdeploy-project-target-does-not-exist?noredirect=1#comment117077794_66213224

Comment: How about the original issue? Do you still have 404 error when trying to access azurewebsite.net?